# Make QMenu have equal width as parent (QPushButton)

Tags: c++, qt, widget, size, width

I have a `QMenu` which is assigned to a `QPushButton` and pops up when the button is pressed. It looks like this:

[image]

However, I'd like to have the width of the menu to be equal the width of the button because as it is now it looks ugly and it's also harder to hit.

I could set a fixed width for the menu by using `setMinimumWidth`, but then I would have to enter a value for the width manually. The size of the button probably is not going to change once it has been created, so the minimum width of the menu does not necessarily have to adapt dynamically. Yet I don't want to hardcode a value.

Both widgets are created in the constructor of my window which is also derived from `QWidget`. I am able to call the `sizeHint` method of my button, but that returns only the 'optimal' width for it. The width it later has in the layout is wider than that.

Now, calling the method `width` on the button does also not return the correct width it should have in the layout, but a width which is wider than that of the button, even if I call it after all child widgets of my window have been assigned to their layout, and the window's layout has been set. I'm not sure why this is; maybe because in the constructor of the window-widget does not yet know the size it is going to be displayed at?

Now, is there a way to make that menu have the width of the button? Or at which point in time can I call the method `width` on the button and it will return me the width the button actually has as it's displayed? The button is also set as the `parent` of the menu. Is there maybe a way to make a widget have the width of its parent?

Here some exemplary code:

```cpp
MainInterface::MainInterface(QWidget *parent){

    //some code

    _moreButton = new QPushButton(tr("&More..."));
    _moreMenu = new QMenu(_moreButton);
    _cmdAction = new QAction(tr("Save as Batch File"), this);
    _moreMenu->addAction(_cmdAction);
    _moreButton->setMenu(_moreMenu);

    //some more code

    _layout->addWidget(_moreButton);
    setLayout(_layout);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use `setWidth`?

Comment: How do you mean that? I know how to set the width of the menu (`setMinimumWidth`) and this also works, but I am unable to retrieve the actual width of that button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem by connecting a slot to the menu's signal `aboutToShow()` that then sets the menus minimum width to the width of the button. This way the menu's width is always appropriately adjusted before it's shown.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you should setup the minimum width of the menu like this:

```
menu->setMinimumWidth( button->width() );
```

At the end of the [`void QWidget::resizeEvent( QResizeEvent* event )`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) or [`void QWidget::showEvent( QShowEvent* event )`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#showEvent) function. But for this you need to subclass `QWidget` and overwrite one of the mentioned functions in that derived class.

```
void Derived::resizeEvent( QResizeEvent* event )
{
    QWidget::resizeEvent( event );

    // Update the size of your your menu here (enough on the first resize) ...
}
```

Or do the same with the `showEvent`.

Comment: `menu->setWidth( button->width() );`

Comment: Hey, the way you're doing it probably works. I would then choose to overwrite the resize event of my window widget (which is a child of `QWidget` anyway), because the button size can basically only change if the windows size changes. This way I won't have to subclass `QButton`. However, I also found a solution which works by connecting the `aboutToShow()` signal of the menu to a slot that updates the latter's width to that of the button.